# Spring MVC Application - Upload image with rename action in a new user form

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

I have form with this url

> localhost:8080/MyApplication/newuser

, in this new user form page it will have a lot of stuff like First name, Last name, email, username etc. Also it will have image block with upload option. Now I have two questions that I cannot figure out the best way to handle it. First, after the user finish the upload the picture (by clicking the upload button), the picture will be displayed in new user form, and all the information that user entered before will be still there? Is it possible?

Second questions is since the form validation will check does username in database already or not, I want the behavior is when user press "Save" in the form with all the validation met, the picture will rename to "user-{$username}.jpg" for example, and save that picture into webapp/WEB-INF/static/images/ folder. I look at this tutorial:http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-tutorial-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-specific-location/, it specify the actual location of saving directory, but if I make my whole project into war format, and then run in another computer, I think it will give me the error said "cannot find the directory" etc. Therefore I am looking for the solution for this two questions.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Here is the project structure I have so far, and I am using java configuration 
[image]

Comment: The second question is discussed very often: and the answers are always the same: do not try to upload anything into the application folders! Instead uses some external directory (and configure the Spring resource handler http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources). btw make the external directory configurable, to that someone how install the application can choose the directory he wants to use

Comment: Is it any reason why we should not upload anything into application folder? @Ralph

Comment: It is mostly a security concern, but also that you are facing with problems while redeploying.